# regret to tell vs regret telling

Tags: grammar

I regret to tell you that your flight has been cancelled

or

I regret telling you that your flight has been cancelled?

Comment: The infinitive *to* versus gerund -- please see previous posts. Also, there's a whole tag http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive-vs-gerund

Comment: @Kris 
In this case there is a difference in meaning, not covered in dictionaries, that means that this has not been dealt with on this site, at all. It is, however, a better fit for ELL.

Comment: @Araucaria True, but was *that* the Q?

Comment: @Kris I *think* so ...

Comment: @Araucaria Apparently, the Q. is *which* is correct, the OP's presumption being one of them may be ungrammatical.

Comment: @Kris I think it's more "what's the difference between ..." but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The cause for regret in the first case is the cancellation of the flight.  In the second case, the cause for regret is the communication of the cancellation, implying that the speaker would rather keep silent in the same situation next time.  Presumably because of the listener acting in an unfair/unpleasant way.

Comment: +1 But pray, why?